# Which model to choose (OLS, fixed-effects, 2SLS, random-effects) in R?

Tags: r, panel-data, 2sls, hausman

I want to perform an analysis on my panel data, but I have troubles finding the best model for my analysis.

I performed an F-test to detect whether the pooled OLS or the fixed effects is more suitable. The results indicate that I should use the fixed effects model.

I also performed a Hausman test to detect whether the fixed or the random effect model is more suitable. The results also indicate that I should use the fixed effects model.

I also performed a Hausman test to see if the OLS or the 2SLS approach is more suitable. Indicating that I should use the 2SLS approach.

My question now:
How do I know whether to use 2SLS or fixed effects?
Is there another test I could perform?
Or should I check for certain assumptions of the model and if yes, which ones?

Comment: I doubt anybody can answer meaningfully based on so little info, you need to tell us more!